# Changing a dropdown column width

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, branding, choice-field

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 and have no license for InfoPath, so it can not be used.

I have made a basic arrangement of newForm, editForm, and displayForm. I am aware this is probably not the best way to do this, but I want to only edit the code in each of those forms .aspx file or include a file to read from. I do not want to edit any base files, if possible, as they are being used in other places.

Initially, when I made this column, there was wrapping and the piece was a static width, but after making a newForm again, it is now no-wrapping, but very long, though I don't recall making any changes.

I have been trying to change the width of a drop-down menu column, (add a column, drop-down choice) but no matter what I've changed in the code it will not affect the form's drop-down size. (Which is about 900-1000px wide) It seems like something is overwriting any width orders, even if I give them an !important. I want it to no wrap with overflow hidden (anything too wide will just be cut off) I have edited the

```
<td width="400px">
```

as well as attempted to use the css as

```
.ms-formbody{}
.menu-item-text{}
```

as well as attempted to directly target the field by its name or id, which are

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="f11{$Pos}" FieldName= "EC">
```

But I am not sure the syntax was correct. I have even tried a few of the javascript solutions on here, which again, I may be using incorrect syntax to target the field, but has also not worked. ( I do not know if I am speaking to the correct field name, for example, since nothing is changing)

Thank you!

Comment: do I need to add the "JS" in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the choice field in Sharepoint list has an auto-size style based on its content.

[image]

---

**To set a width style for `all` choice fields in your list form,**

- Open the Edit / New form in a new tab.
- Edit the page.
- Add a script editor with the blow CSS style

**CSS**

```
<style>
select {
width:300px !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

---

**To set a width style for `Specific` choice fields in your list form,**

- Open the Edit / New form in a new tab.
- Edit the page.
- Add a script editor with the blow Js Script with your own field ID

**JS**

```
document.querySelector("select[id='FieldID'").style= "Width:300px !important";
```

[image]

Check also this [link](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/) to know how to edit the form and add script editor